# Code Coverage 71% (5/7)

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

Not sure where am I missing but not able to get over 75%. Below is the Class and a test class:

**Apex Class: SetCustomOwnershipOnOpportunity**

```
public class SetCustomOwnershipOnOpportunity
{
    public static void SetCustomOwnership(ID opportunityID)
    {
        Opportunity opp = [select Id, OwnerId, Owner.FswUserID__c from Opportunity where Id = :opportunityID];
        List<User> user = [select Id, FswUserID__c, ProfileId, Profile.Name from User where Id = :opp.OwnerId];
        User systemUser = [select Id, FswUserID__c from User where Alias = 'System'];

        if(user.size() > 0 && opp.Owner.FswUserID__c != user[0].FswUserID__c)
        {
            opp.Owner.FswUserID__c = user[0].FswUserID__c;  
            update opp;  
        }   
    }

}
```

**Apex Class: SetCustomOwnershipOnOpportunityTest**

```
@isTest
private class SetCustomOwnershipOnOpportunityTest
{    
    @isTest
    private static void SetCustomOwnershipTest()    
    {        
        ID recordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account'            
        AND isActive = TRUE AND Name = 'Commercial Account'][0].Id;

        Account acc = new Account(Name='test1234', RecordTypeId=recordTypeId, Type='Client',            
        IndustrySegment__c='Casual Eatery');
        insert acc;

        Opportunity theOpportunity = new Opportunity(Name='test1234', AccountId=acc.Id,             
        CloseDate=Date.today(), StageName='1 - Researching');        
        insert theOpportunity;        

        SetCustomOwnershipOnOpportunity.SetCustomOwnership(theOpportunity.Id);      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your if statement will *never be true*, because opp.Owner.FswUserId__c will *always* equal users[0].FswUserId__c. You also have additional issues related to the logic, since you're apparently trying to update a user via the opportunity, plus your logic isn't bulkified. Unfortunately, you're going to have to go back to the drawing board to figure out what you're trying to do (you may want to ask a new question).